# Timestamp format modification in Oracle 10g

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Im new to databases and using Oracle 10g XE.

The query `SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP( ORA_ROWSCN ) FROM MYTABLE;` gives a value of type timestamp.

However I want the value of type timestamp from the query mentioned above but in the following format `2013-07-24 12:18:03`

How do I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In other words, a date does not have a format; it is _displayed_ how you ask and you can convert it to a specific format as long as it's a string. It's always best to use dates as dates and only convert when you want to display.

Comment: The application im using needs the value of type timestamp in the format i mentioned above. Please help. I have to pass this timestamp value to a variable.

Comment: Pass the value to what kind of variable? What language is the application in and how is it accessing the DB/executing the query? If you need it as a string then the question Ben linked to shows you how to do that with `to_char`.

Comment: [You can find the details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830323/timestamp-compatibility-while-performing-delta-import-in-solr) @AlexPoole