# Timestamp compatibility while performing delta import in solr

Tags: database, solr, dataimporthandler, solr4

Im new to solr.I have successfully indexed oracle 10g xe database. Im trying to perform delta import on the same.
The delta query requires a comparison of `last_modified` column of the table with `${dih.last_index_time}`.
However in my application I do not have such a column . Also, i cannot add this column. Therefore i used '`scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn)`' to give the value of the required timestamps. This query returns the value of type timestamp in the following format `24-JUL-13 12.42.32.000000000 PM` and `dih.last_index_time` is in the format `2013-07-24 12:18:03`. So, I changed the format of `dih.last_index_time` as `to_timestamp('${dih.last_index_time}', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS').`

My Data-config looks like this -

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX:xe" user="XXXXXXXX" password="XXXXXXX" /> 
<document name="product_info">
<entity name="PRODUCT" pk="PID" query="SELECT * FROM PRODUCT" deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PID=${dih.delta.id}" deltaQuery="SELECT PID FROM PRODUCT WHERE scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn) > to_timestamp('${dih.last_index_time}', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')">
  <field column="PID" name="id" /> 
  <field column="PNAME" name="itemName" /> 
  <field column="INITQTY" name="itemQuantity" />
  <field column="REMQTY" name="remQuantity" />
  <field column="PRICE" name="itemPrice" /> 
  <field column="SPECIFICATION" name="specifications" /> 
  <entity name="SUB_CATEGORY" query="SELECT * FROM SUB_CATEGORY WHERE SCID=${PRODUCT.SCID}">
    <field column="SUBCATNAME" name="brand" /> 
    <entity name="CATEGORY" query="SELECT CNAME FROM CATEGORY WHERE CID=${SUB_CATEGORY.CID}">
      <field column="CNAME" name="itemCategory" /> 
    </entity>
  </entity>
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

However,This is not working and im getting the following error -

```
Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PID= Processing Document # 1
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Please help me out!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and had more success with *to_date*.  But looking at this again, it just looks like perhaps you just need to quote your delta id in the delatImportQuery:

*deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PID=**'**${dih.delta.id}**'**"*